# C# "A heap has been corrupted" using sam-ba.dll

Tags: c#, pointers, atmel, heap-corruption

I'm writing a C# program that makes a call to the `AT91Boot_Scan` function in `sam-ba.dll`. In the [documentation](http://support.garz-fricke.com/products/Santaro/Linux/Documentation/sam-ba%20user%20guide.pdf) for this DLL, the signature for this function is `void AT91Boot_Scan(char *pDevList)`. The purpose of this function is to scan and return a list of connected devices.

**Problem**: My current problem is that every time I call this function from C#, the code in the DLL throws an `a heap has been corrupted` exception.

---

**Aside**: From what I understand from reading the [documentation](http://support.garz-fricke.com/products/Santaro/Linux/Documentation/sam-ba%20user%20guide.pdf), the `char *pDevList` parameter is a pointer to an array of buffers that the function can use to store the device names. However, when calling the method from C#, IntelliSense reports that the signature for this function is actually `void AT91Boot_Scan(ref byte pDevList)`

[image: AT91Boot_Scan signature]

I was sort of confused by why this is. A single byte isn't long enough to be a pointer. We would need 4 bytes for 32-bit and 8 bytes for 64-bit... If it's the `ref` keyword that is making this parameter a pointer, then what byte should I be passing in? The first byte in my *array of buffers* or the first byte of the *first buffer*?

---

**Code**: The C# method I've written that calls this function is as follows.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Returns a string array containing the names of connected devices
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string[] LoadDeviceList()
    {
        const int MAX_NUM_DEVICES = 10;
        const int BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME = 100;
        SAMBADLL samba = new SAMBADLL();
        string[] deviceNames = new string[MAX_NUM_DEVICES];
        try
        {
            unsafe
            {
                // Allocate an array (of size MAX_NUM_DEVICES) of pointers 
                byte** deviceList = stackalloc byte*[MAX_NUM_DEVICES];

                for (int n = 0; n < MAX_NUM_DEVICES; n++)
                {
                    // Allocate a buffer of size 100 for the device name
                    byte* deviceNameBuffer = stackalloc byte[BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME];

                    // Assign the buffer to a pointer in the deviceList
                    deviceList[n] = deviceNameBuffer;
                }

                // Create a pointer to the deviceList
                byte* pointerToStartOfList = *deviceList;

                // Call the function. A heap has been corrupted error is thrown here.
                samba.AT91Boot_Scan(ref* pointerToStartOfList);

                // Read back out the names by converting the bytes to strings
                for (int n = 0; n < MAX_NUM_DEVICES; n++)
                {
                    byte[] nameAsBytes = new byte[BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME];
                    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)deviceList[n], nameAsBytes, 0, BYTES_PER_DEVICE_NAME);
                    string nameAsString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(nameAsBytes);
                    deviceNames[n] = nameAsString;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return deviceNames;
    }
```

---

**My attempt at a solution**: I noticed that the line `byte* pointerToStartOfList = *deviceList;` wasn't correctly assigning the pointer for `deviceList` to `pointerToStartOfList`. The address was always off by 0x64.

[image: pointers]

I thought if I hard-coded in a 0x64 offset then the two addresses would match and all would be fine. `pointerToStartOfList += 0x64;`
[image]

However despite forcing the addresses to match I was still getting a `a heap has been corrupted` error.

**My thoughts**: I think in my code I'm either not creating the array of buffers correctly, or I'm not passing the pointer for said array correctly .

Comment: Is MAX_NUM_DEVICES definitely large enough? What you've done so far looks ok as far as I can tell from the documentation... Only thing, perhaps it shouldn't be `ref*` and you should just pass the pointer.

Comment: Yes, definitely. The documentation for sam-ba.dll doesn't explicitly say, but they provided a code example where their number of devices was 5 (search for `CHAR *strConnectedDevices[5];`) I tried to copy their code example but it seems to be written in `C++` and not `C#`

Comment: This library was not designed very well and is really only suitable to be called from a C++ program.  The actual argument type is `string`, not `ref byte`.  Technically you can fix it by decompiling the interop library with ildasm.exe, modify the .il file to fix the argument type and putting it back together with ilasm.exe

Comment: @ Matthew Watson: Yeah... I thought the `ref*` part was weird too, but If I don't do it you'll notice that `pointerToStartOfList` is actually a `byte*` and not `byte` type. So I end up with a `cannot convert from 'ref byte*' to 'ref byte'` error. If I try casting it to byte then I get `A ref or out value must be an assignable variable` error.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Aww man, really? That's a real shame >.< Thank you though I'll try that. If I don't have any luck with that I'll try writing my own wrapper class in C++  that I can then call from C#...Ultimately, I really do need to put this in a C# program.

Comment: @Calseon We have often had to wrap "troublesome" C/C++ libraries in a more sensible 'C' wrapper to make it possible to call it from C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not get `sam-ba.dll` to work. I had tried writing a C++ wrapper around the DLL but even then it was still throwing the `a heap has been corrupted` error. My final solution was to just embed the SAM-BA executable, `sam-ba.exe`, along with all of its dependencies inside my C# program.

Then, whenever I needed to use it I would run `sam-ba.exe` in command line mode and pass it the relevant arguments. Section 5.1 in the [SAM-BA documentation](http://support.garz-fricke.com/products/Santaro/Linux/Documentation/sam-ba%20user%20guide.pdf) provides instructions on how to run `sam-ba.exe` in command line mode.

i.e.

```
SAM-BA.exe \usb\ARM0 AT91SAM9G25-EK myCommand.tcl
```